# TabIndex for two control contained with a table cell ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net

I have a weird issue that I am being asked to fix but alas I have thus far drawn a blank. As the title suggests I am trying to get the tab order for two text boxes to follow one after the other.

The idea is (and this is inherited code rather than that of my own design) that a routine is call that builds atable cell inserting two text boxes and one  link. This is then returned and foreach line in the table a new copy of this cell is generated.

I have tried setting the TabIndex for the text boxes and find that when I tab I only get as far as the first box (txtPound) and never the second (txtPence).

I can't decide if the issue is due to trying to do this in a TableCell or whether its something else completely.

Hopefully that's clear but should you require any further info then I will try to supply it.

I have included a striped down version of the code below, essentially this gets added to a table row in a the aspx pace.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 private TableCell EstimateInputs(Brief item)
        {
    TableCell td = new TableCell();        

                TextBox txtPounds = new TextBox();

                string[] agencyCosts;                  
                txtPounds.TabIndex = 1;
                td.Controls.Add(txtPounds);

                //td.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<span>.</span>"));

                TextBox txtPence = new TextBox();
                                txtPence.MaxLength = 2;


                txtPence.TabIndex = 2;
                td.Controls.Add(txtPence);

                td.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</p></fieldset>"));
        }
```

Comment: Where and when do you generate these controls programatically and to what control are you adding this TableCell? Are you recreating them on every postback with the same ID as before(i would assign an ID at least to the Textboxes).

Comment: I think the root of the problem is that you need to increment the TabIndex, which is currently going to be "1" or "2" for every TextBox.  Can you include at least the header for the event handler this code occurs in?  Then at least we could get an idea if there are any EventArgs that could be used to set a TabIndex value.

Comment: I have added the header for the method. The control is used like this tr.Cells.Add(EstimateInputs(item));. This is within a loop so multiple of this things can exist so I think there is definitely something to be said for the recurring 1/2 issue mentioned by pseudocoder.

Comment: Did you try not to define TabIndex from code? As far as I remember . Net will do it automatically if it's not defined.

Comment: Yep - this tab index is to try and resolve the issue. As it stood you never get to the second box without and you have the same issue with the tabIndex.

Comment: So the solution... Believe it or not there was a JavaScript function that captured All but numerical inputs. Alas a tab key is non numerical, so it was getting ignored on these two text boxes. Needless to say the language that came out of my mouth when I saw it was less than polite. That's for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it ended up being a complete red herring. turns out that there was a little JavaScript function that is applied to text boxes that deal with monetary values. it stops anything other than a numerical key press which means it includes the tab key.

So the mystery is solved - thanks for the help.